# Calling async method does not set member variable

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

This code it´s write in C# in visual studio 2012 I ´ve using winrt tool kit

Hi I tried create this loadGrupos to catch the file grupo.txt and read and load his content in to the class Grupos but I don´t know what´s happen the list grupos recive the content from the json but when I callend the loadGrupos the variable grupos don´t expose nothing.
I really don´t know what´s going on. I tried debug and I didn´t found any error.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using Windows.Storage;
    using Windows.ApplicationModel;
    using WinRTXamlToolkit.IO.Extensions;
    using Windows.UI.Popups;
    namespace xxx;
    public class MyJConverter
    {

    public String _Path;
    //private Windows.ApplicationModel.Package package;
    //   private Windows.Storage.StorageFolder installedLocation;
    private StorageFolder _Folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    //KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary
    public MyJConverter() {
    //  package = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current;
    //   installedLocation = package.InstalledLocation;
    }

    public void save(Object obj)
    {
    _Path = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

    gravandoUmDocumento("data",_Path);

    }
    public void saveGrupo(Object obj)
    {

    _Path = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

    gravandoUmDocumento("grupo", _Path);

    }



    public async void gravandoUmDocumento(String nomeDoArquivo,String menssagem) {




    //  var _Folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    // var _Folder  = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
    //await menssagem.WriteToFile(nomeDoArquivo + "1.txt", KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary);
    await menssagem.WriteToFile(nomeDoArquivo + ".txt", _Folder);
    }
        private List<Ano> anos;

 public List<Ano> load()
 {
        leituraDeUmArquivo("data").Wait();
 if (anos != null)
 {        
    return anos;

 }
 return null;
     }


private List<Grupos> grupos;

public List<Grupos> Grupos
    {
    get { return grupos; }
    set { grupos = value; }
    }

    public List<Grupos> loadGrupos()
    {
       leituraDeUmArquivo("grupo").Wait();

        {
            if (grupos != null)
            {

                return grupos;   
            }
            else
                return null;
        }


    }
    public async Task leituraDeUmArquivo(String arquivoASerLido)
    {
    String leitura = "";
    //leitura do data
    try
    {
    // settings

    var _Path =arquivoASerLido + ".txt";
    // acquire file
    var _File = await _Folder.GetFileAsync(_Path);


    // read content
    leitura = (String) await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(_File);
    //    leitura = (String)_ReadThis;
    }
    catch {
    //     leituraDeUmArquivo(arquivoASerLido);
    }

    if (leitura != "")
    {
            if (arquivoASerLido.Equals("data"))
            {
                    try
            {
                    anos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Ano>>(leitura);
            }
            catch { 

            }
            }
            if (arquivoASerLido.Equals("grupo"))
            {
                    try{
                    grupos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Grupos>>(leitura);
                }
                    catch { }

            }

        }


    }

}
```

HI I did the modifications you recomend but the problem didn´t solved so I post all my code.
I really didn´t found why the winrt can´t load the file, some time win 8 load some times no.
Now with the modificiations the app block and do go to front.

if I go with debug the visual found the file, if I go only run no.

Comment: I've changed title/removed whitespace in the code. Feel free to revert/update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be warning about "calling async method without awaiting" (or something like this).

You need to `await` for completion of `async` method instead of just calling it.

I.e. cheap and dirty (not good idea for WinRT) approach is to call [Task.Wait](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235635.aspx) on result of `leituraDeUmArquivo` (the method need to be updated to return `Task`):

```
leituraDeUmArquivo("grupo").Wait();
```

Better approach is to make code properly asynchronous and just `await` call to `leituraDeUmArquivo` (your `loadGrupos` function will likely need to be marked `async` too and handled appropriately).

Note: to make `await`/ `.Wait()` working `leituraDeUmArquivo` should return `Task`.

```
public async Task leituraDeUmArquivo(String arquivoASerLido)
// don't need to touch body of the method.
```

Comment: Right, you just called an asynch without waiting it, so you do not know when it is executed.

Comment: Your description of the solution is correct, but your example calls `Wait` instead of using `await`, which is wrong.

Comment: @Gustavo: A good principle is "avoid `async void`" (i.e., use `async Task` instead). One of the reasons is that you can then `await` calls to that method.

Comment: @StephenCleary, you are absolutely right - `leituraDeUmArquivo` does not return `Task` (return `void` instead) so it can't be `.Wait`'ed/`await`'ed. `Wait()` is cheap and dirty way to wait for completion of `async` operation and definitely wrong choice for WinRT app.